# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown compression type id: 5

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm getting the following error when trying to read from Kafka

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown compression type id: 5
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.CompressionType.forId(CompressionType.java:46)
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.Record.compressionType(Record.java:260)
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.LogEntry.isCompressed(LogEntry.java:89)
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.RecordsIterator.makeNext(RecordsIterator.java:70)
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.RecordsIterator.makeNext(RecordsIterator.java:34)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AbstractIterator.maybeComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:79)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:45)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:772)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:473)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1038)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:995)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerThread.run(KafkaConsumerThread.java:243)
```

Any idea what this could be or where I should be looking?

Comment: This is often caused by the incompatible version between client and server. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6315?focusedCommentId=16619720&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16619720 to see if you had a similar setup.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka supports these compression codec - **NONE, GZIP, SNAPPY, LZ4, ZSTD**. And there compression types stand between 0-4  (*as described below in the link also*)

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/record/CompressionType.java#L169

If you are using different compression codec beyond these, you need to change it to the one, which Kafka supports.

Comment: We are using "lz4". But we did have a Kafka version upgrade recently, so as another comment mentioned, that is probably the most likely cause.

Comment: okay, so if you are using the LZ4 compression already, then it's most likely the version compatibility issue

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue its due to clients incompatible version and topics created on an old version of kafka .

Check your kafka consumer client version and your kafka version.