# Reduce the filesize of a JPG file in java

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot, filesize, javax.imageio

We have generated a JPG file by using 
`org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot` class

```
File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
File dest = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Images\\29_18-03-20-07-11-47.jpg");
FileHandler.copy(src, dest);
```

As the generated image is having file size of 1.5MB to 2.9MB size. We want to reduce the file size to kbs.

we tried ImageIO but the generated image is not having original file color space/color profile.

```
File input = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Images\\29_18-03-20-07-11-47.jpg");
File compressedImageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Images\\compressed_image7.jpg");

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);
Iterator<ImageWriter writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
writer.setOutput(ios);

ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(0.05f);         
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
```

Could not share the image or screen shot

Could someone let me know how can I reduce the filesize

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize the original image into a common size of image in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305670/how-to-resize-the-original-image-into-a-common-size-of-image-in-java)

Comment: I tried that one too but nothing helped

Comment: What's the size (in pixels) of the image?

Comment: Size of the image is 2048X1536

Answer (score 1):

Try using lossless JPEG

```
ImageWriter writer= (ImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
ImageWriteParam param= writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(param.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("JPEG-LS");
writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File(path)));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
```

Comment: JPEG is lossy by default. JPEG-LS is lossless!

Comment: Getting  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown compression type! Tried JPEG also but no change in the image

Comment: refer to this thread if you are using kafka [javalangIllegalArgumentException: Unknown compression type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458360/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unknown-compression-type-id-5)